# Post Data using Chai HTTP with Express is not registering

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, chai, chai-http

I'm looking for some guidance on how my test code can send post data. In my unit test, I would expect that `.send` would properly set up the data. However, at runtime there isn't any data on `req.body` resulting in `TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined`. Here's my setup. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Test Code

```
  describe("/myTest", () => {
    it("should work with valid data", (done) => {
      let data = {
        "key": value
      };

      chai.request(api).post("/path").send(data).end((err, res) => {
        let val = res.body.value;
        assert.ok(val);
        done();
      });
    })
  });
```

Express Code:

```
app.post('/path', async function(req, res) {
  let data = req.body;
  let val = data.key;
  res.json({'value': val});
});
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `res.send()` ?

Comment: thanks for the idea. The error happens before that actually at `data.key` but res.json works too: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json

*I edited question since there was a typo*

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine:

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/path', async function (req, res) {
  let data = req.body;
  let val = data.key;
  res.json({ value: val });
});

module.exports = app;
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const api = require('./app');

chai.use(chaiHttp);
const { assert } = chai;

describe('/myTest', () => {
  it('should work with valid data', (done) => {
    let data = {
      key: 'value',
    };

    chai
      .request(api)
      .post('/path')
      .send(data)
      .end((err, res) => {
        let val = res.body.value;
        assert.ok(val);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  /myTest
    ✓ should work with valid data (44ms)


  1 passing (47ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 app.js   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```